# How can I build a custom dynamic widget like linkedin to insert into another website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget

[Linkedin Widget Creation page](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile)

I need to create a custom widget like this where I can give user the code within the script tag and they can include that into their own website.It would be better if it can be built on React.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to embed a some web content from your web server on another page.

A widget builder usually generates code that contains an iframe and points to a page (or route on your server that generates a page) with various [URL parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) that allow the look and contents of the widget to be customised by the widget creator.

Edit: Script tag widgets usually inject an iframe or HTML retrieved from your web server